# Enviar imagem gerada pelo PHP (GD) para o Amazon S3

Tags: php, upload, amazon-aws, gd

Possuo o seguinte código para enviar uma imagem upada no meu bucket S3:

```
// Send.class.php
public function sendFile($file, $file_name) {
    try {
        $s3 -> putObject([
            "Bucket" => "mybucket",
            "Key" => "image/".$file_name,
            "SourceFile" => $file,
            "ACL" => "public-read"
        ]);

        return true;
    } catch(S3Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}

// index.php
$send = new Send();

$send -> sendFile($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

O código acima funciona corretamente, porém, quero enviar imagens geradas pelo PHP (inicialmente originadas no JavaScript - jQuery - onde estou usando o plugin `jqScribble`: https://github.com/jimdoescode/jqScribble/blob/master/image_save.php) para o meu bucket também, então, tentei:

```
// index.php

error_reporting(E_ALL); // mostrar erros
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); // mostrar erros

$send = new Send();

$data = $_POST["imgdt"]; // imagem originada no JavaScript

$data = substr($data, strpos($data, ",") + 1);

$data = base64_decode($data);
$imgRes = imagecreatefromstring($data);

ob_start();
imagepng($imgRes);
$imageImage = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$send -> sendFile($imageImage, "test.png");
```

Mas, o seguinte erro é retornado:

> Fatal error: in /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php
>   on line 299

E a função que corresponde à linha do erro (299) é:

```
function try_fopen($filename, $mode)
{
    $ex = null;
    set_error_handler(function () use ($filename, $mode, &$ex) {
        $ex = new \RuntimeException(sprintf( // linha 299
            'Unable to open %s using mode %s: %s',
            $filename,
            $mode,
            func_get_args()[1]
        ));
    });

    $handle = fopen($filename, $mode);
    restore_error_handler();

    if ($ex) {
        /** @var $ex \RuntimeException */
        throw $ex;
    }

    return $handle;
}
```

Pelo que entendi, o erro ocorre pois não é possível abrir o arquivo utilizando a função `fopen`, porém, não sei a quais alternativas recorrer. Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Posso estar enganado, parece que esta faltando um pedaço do erro, me diz uma coisa, está usando a versão 5.2 do PHP?

Comment: O erro que aparece é somente essa mensagem mesmo. Estou usando a versão 7.0 que vem como padrão no Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Verifica o código fonte após o a tentativa de upload ou inspetor de elementos, pode ser que esteja retornando HTML.

Comment: Infelizmente, retorna apenas o erro: `<br>
<b>Fatal error</b>:   in <b>/var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/functions.php</b> on line <b>299</b><br>`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento creio que o erro esteja na imagem gerada e não em outra parte do código (como o próprio erro informa), visto que para imagens upadas (`$_FILE`) funciona normalmente. Porém, não sei onde estou errando.

Comment: O primeiro parâmetro da função `sendFile()` espera um path de um arquivo físico. Mas está passando como  stream/resource do output buffer `ob_get_contents()`.  Salve a imagem gerada no disco e informe o path.

Comment: @DanielOmine porém eu não quero salvar no disco a imagem, apenas enviar diretamente para o S3

Comment: Essa função apresentada na pergunta não suporta o que quer fazer. Crie o arquivo, execute a função e exclua-o. Está a complicar algo simples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `putObject` espera um caminho de arquivo, mas você está passando um stream. Pra isso é possível utilizar o Stream Wrapper do S3, que habilita a utilização do protocolo (wrapper) `s3://`

Sua função deve ficar parecida com isso:

```
public function sendFile($fileContents, $file_name) {
    try {

        // registra o stream wrapper pra poder usar o protocolo s3://
        $s3->registerStreamWrapper();

        // abre o stream
        $s3Stream = fopen('s3://'.'mybucket'.'/image/'.$file_name, 'w', false, stream_context_create(
            array(
                's3' => array(
                    'ContentType'=> 'image/png'
                )
            )
        ) );

        //escreve
        fwrite($s3Stream, $fileContents);

        //fecha
        fclose($s3Stream);

        return true;
    } catch(S3Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Você encontra a documentação aqui:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html